# How to add a new system call in OS/161?

Tags: c, linux, operating-system, unix, os161

I am trying to add a new system call in my OS/161 code, but I am having trouble figuring out where to add the prototypes. I believe you're supposed to add it to the kernel space and user space, but I'm not sure exactly which files to put the prototype in. Is there a guide somewhere that explains how to add a sample system call in OS/161?

As a test I am trying to add a function, `printone()`, that when the user runs that program, it will just print a "1".

Comment: What that be [this OS/161](http://www.eecs.harvard.edu/~syrah/os161/)?

Comment: Where is the `printone()` system call going to write to?  Are you going to provide a file descriptor, or will it write to the console, or what?

Comment: It looks like there are at least two universities using OS/161 as a monicker for a teaching O/S.

Answer (score 2):

Add another system call number, e.g. `SYS_print1` in [`callno.h`](https://www.student.cs.uwaterloo.ca/~cs350/common/os161-src-html/callno_8h-source.html#l00019) or wherever those constants like `SYS_fork` and `SYS_read` are defined.

Find the place where they are used to choose functions to call, looks like it should be [`mips_syscall()`](https://www.student.cs.uwaterloo.ca/~cs350/common/os161-src-html/syscall_8c-source.html#l00049). Although, I'm not sure why in this version of the source code there's only `SYS_reboot` used to call `sys_reboot()`. This source code reference is probably incomplete. The comment suggests that:

```
00049 mips_syscall(struct trapframe *tf)
00050 {
...
00070         switch (callno) {
00071             case SYS_reboot:
00072                 err = sys_reboot(tf->tf_a0);
00073                 break;
00074 
00075             /* Add stuff here */
00076  
00077             default:
00078                 kprintf("Unknown syscall %d\n", callno);
00079                 err = ENOSYS;
00080                 break;
00081         }
...
00108 }
```

Similarly add your `case SYS_print1:` and implement the functionality in a dedicated function, say `sys_print1()`.

That should be it for the kernel side.

The user-mode prototype for `print1()` can be declared in [`unistd.h`](https://www.student.cs.uwaterloo.ca/~cs350/common/os161-src-html/include_2unistd_8h-source.html) alongside with `read()` and the like.

Looks like the user-mode implementation of `read()` might be in an assembly file. And that's reasonable since in the end it should execute the MIPS `syscall` instruction unavailable directly in C. You should implement `print1()` in a similar fashion (load `SYS_print1` into the appropriate register and execute `syscall`).